# How can i read file and get 10 digit number only

Tags: php

I have a file in `nodepage` where data record are available. I want to extract only the `10 digit` numeric fields and put them into an array.

How can I achieve this? I am new to PHP.

Here is the data format in file:

```
STD OBD500-450-0514SIPPOOLPLAN
15/05/16
Page 878
Product Type: SIP Trunk Channel Line Int
Bill Number
PO Number 0
Bill Date
18:38:41 7045693328 Vodafone-MUM 00:01:00  4 0.60 18:51:59 9819286096 Vodafone-MUM 00:00:22 2 0.30
18:41:56 9833329668 Vodafone-MUM 00:03:51 16 2.40 18:52:08 9822965734 Idea-MH      00:01:07 5 0.75
18:42:23 9075613876 Idea-MH      00:01:22  6 0.90 18:53:59 9822965734 Idea-MH      00:00:53 4 0.60
18:44:07 9403358204 BSNL-MH      00:00:43  3 0.45 18:54:30 8691955808 Idea-MUM     00:01:09 5 0.75
```

Comment: apart from teh spelling mistakes, it isn't clear what the exact output required here is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 preg_match_all("/(\d{10})[\s|$]/", $string, $output);

 var_dump($output);
```

Preg_match_all will search all lines of $string and look for numbers `\d` that is 10 digits long `{10}` and make sure there is a space or end of string after the digits `[\s|$]` to make sure it's not a 11 digit number.

output of above code:

```
array(2
    0=>array(8
            0 => 7045693328 
            1 => 9819286096 
            2 => 9833329668 
            3 => 9822965734 
            4 => 9075613876 
            5 => 9822965734 
            6 => 9403358204 
            7 => 8691955808 
    )
    1=>array(8
            0 => 7045693328
            1 => 9819286096
            2 => 9833329668
            3 => 9822965734
            4 => 9075613876
            5 => 9822965734
            6 => 9403358204
            7 => 8691955808
    )
)
```

Comment: Why you have duplicate result in array?

Comment: It's not duplicate. It's how preg_match works. $output[0] is the full match and $output[1] is the part you want to extract from the string. In this case it's almost duplicate (there is a space after each digit in $output[0] and $output[1] has only actual match)